# How to tackle the smooth Poincaré conjecture

Tags: open-problems, differential-topology, dg.differential-geometry, ho.history-overview

The last remaining problem in this whole "everything is a sphere" business, is the *smooth Poincaré conjecture* in dimension 4: If $X\simeq_\text{homo.eq.} S^4$ then $X\approx_\text{diffeo} S^4$.  Freedman showed that this holds if we replace "diffeomorphism" by "homeomorphism", so another viewpoint would be that $S^4$ has no exotic smooth structures.

Restated: If $X$ is a connected, closed smooth 4-manifold with $\pi_1X=1$ and $H_*X\cong H_*S^4$, then $X\approx_\text{diffeo}S^4$.

$\newcommand\pt{\mathrm{pt}}$This was told to me by Michael Hutchings, who motivationally remarked a way to solve it (Edit: not an original suggestion of his):
*Find a symplectic structure on $X-\lbrace \pt\rbrace$ which is standard near the puncture-point.*
Then we're done by "Recognition of $\mathbb{R}^4$": Let $(M,\omega)$ be a noncompact symplectic 4-manifold such that $H_\ast(M)\cong H_\ast (\pt)$. Suppose there exist compact sets $K_0\subset M$ and $K_1\subset\mathbb{R}^4$ and a symplectomorphism $\phi:(M-K_0,\omega)\to(\mathbb{R}^4-K_1,\omega_\text{std})$. Then $\phi$ extends to a symplectomorphism $(M,\omega)\to(\mathbb{R}^4,\omega_\text{std})$, after removing slightly bigger compact sets.

I am ignorant to the size of this wall (the conjecture) and the ability to make an indent in it. But the above idea is pretty cool, even if not anymore helpful than the original statement. The Poincaré Conjecture (in dimension 3) was solved using Hamilton's idea of Ricci flow. This leads me to ask:
**Is there another idea proposed to tackle this conjecture?** Or a failed attempt?

Comment: as your formulation *non-smooth* is somewhat misleading let me clarify this point: Perelman used the Ricci flow (with surgery) to prove the 3-dimensional Poincare conjecture. In dimension three it doesn't matter whether you say *homeomorphic* or *diffeomorphic*.

Comment: On the other hand, there's an emerging point of view where people think it's likely that all compact 4-manifolds should admit countably-infinite many distinct smooth structures.  This isn't a *deep* rationale -- it's just that for "sufficiently large" 4-manifolds, there appears to be always arguments to this effect.  And "sufficiently large" manifolds have been getting smaller and smaller recently. See Stern's notes from this talk: http://math.uci.edu/~rstern/Cornell_2012.pdf

Comment: Ah I was at this conference! Interesting point.

Comment: One failed attempted was discussed in Ryan's question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/71031

Comment: The business about finding a symplectic structure on $X-\{pt\}$ is not my original suggestion, nor a program that I am suggesting anyone try to carry out. It is just a motivational remark I made when introducting Gromov's theorem on the recognition of ${\mathbb R}^4$.

Comment: With a technique called mean curvature flow, maybe it is possible to resolve smooth poincare conjecture.. who knows?

Comment: Mean curvature of what submanifold and of what ambient manifold? Is this really a programme that people are working through? If so, could you give references?

Comment: Recently a preprint claiming a proof appeared on arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.11904

Comment: @ChrisGerig I'm a little confused by your phrase "last remaining problem"; isn't it still open whether $S^{2n}$ has a unique smooth structure for $2n\ge 126$? For example, it's stated as Conjecture 1.17 by [Wang and Xu](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02184).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In principle the Ricci flow (with surgery) could also be used to prove the smooth Poincaré conjecture in dimension $4$.

There are some major problems to be overcome in this approach (problems which did not arise in dimension $3$, such as the absence of Hamilton–Ivey pinching estimates, and the new "hole-punch" singularities, as opposed to the "neck-pinch") and I know that some people are indeed working on these issues.

If you are interested, there are quite a few papers on Ricci flow on $4$-manifolds, starting with the work of Hamilton ([Four-manifolds with positive curvature operator](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0862046) and [Four-manifolds with positive isotropic curvature](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1456308)) and more recent work of Chen–Zhu ([Ricci flow with surgery on four-manifolds with positive isotropic curvature](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2258799)) and Chen–Tang–Zhu ([Complete classification of compact four-manifolds with positive isotropic curvature](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1999)) and many others.

Comment: Could you say why in principle (supposing one can get to grips with the singularities) the Ricci flow might help prove S4PC? I can imagine it might help produce an Einstein metric, but what then?

Comment: Roughly the idea is the following. One would need to prove that a Ricci flow with surgery exists in $4D$ (analogously to the case of $3D$), and that on a topological $S^4$ the flow becomes extinct in finite time. Then one would have to prove a "canonical neighborhood" theorem which should imply that before becoming extinct, all components of the manifold have positive curvature operator (or locally they split as products of lower dim. manifolds with this property). A theorem of Hamilton (and Bohm-Wilking in any dimension) then implies that all such components are diffeomorphic to space forms

Comment: (or products of lower dimensional space forms). This program, initiated by Hamilton, has been carried out by Chen-Zhu if the initial metric has positive isotropic curvature, see arxiv:0504478. I think the general case is still pretty much open, and as the other comments suggest there is really no strong evidence for S4PC, so it's possible that this program cannot be carried out in general. 

Comment: Thanks for explaining! The thing that sounds most mysterious to me is how to bring to bear the topological hypothesis to prove finite-time extinction. Is there any proposed mechanism for using that assumption?

Comment: There's several serious issues with this approach. There are $\kappa$-noncollapsed solitons in 4 dimensions, such as the 3D Bryant soliton x $\mathbb{R}$ or $S^1$, or $S^2\times \mathbb{R}^2$ which might occur as blow-up limits of finite-time singularities (the $S^3\times \mathbb{R}$ soliton or 4D Bryant soliton shouldn't be a problem). Doing surgery to proceed along the flow past these singularities might drastically change the topology of the manifold, and it's not clear that one can proceed without changing the topology while simplifying the geometry.




Comment: Even if one can resolve the formation of singularities issue, it's also not clear how to prove that a flow on the 4-sphere might have a finite-time singularity. The proof in 3-dimensions by Colding-Minicozzi uses some special properties of minimal surfaces and their stability operators. It's not clear how to generalize this to 4-dimensions (although I certainly haven't thought about it). But there might be some other approach using e.g. Gauss-Bonnet. 

Finally, if one could prove that it converges to an Einstein metric or a soliton, then there still remains the classification of these!

Comment: Yes, there are many issues that nobody knows how to deal with. The finite time extinction might be possibly attacked by a minimax argument like Perelman (which does not use minimal surfaces). Mimimax arguments are usually sensitive to the topology, so that is how the topological assumptions could be used. I agree that controlling the topology after surgery might be extremely hard. Lastly, I think the point is not to construct an Einstein metric or soliton, but rather to show that before collapsing, all components have positive curvature operator (or almost so), so that they must be space forms

Comment: @ YangMills: I'm not sure one should expect this in general. For example, there might be an Einstein metric on a compact manifold with positive scalar curvature, but mixed signed eigenvalues of the curvature operator, which would shrink in finite time, but wouldn't satisfy an analogue of Hamilton-Ivey pinching. However, I know nothing about the classification of Einstein manifolds with positive scalar curvature in 4D or higher (although I think LeBrun has some results on this). 

Comment: This might be a silly question, but do we even know that an Einstein metric on a topological 4-sphere must be the round metric?

Comment: It is definitely still an open problem whether there are exotic Einstein metrics with positive scalar curvature on the standard $4$-sphere, see e.g. http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~anderson/einsurv.pdf page 19.

Answer (score 26):

It seems to me your question implicitly assumes that the 4d smooth Poincaré conjecture (S4PC) is true.  But if you were to take a poll of experts  I think you would find that most of them suspect it is false.  (See also Ryan's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97464/how-to-tackle-the-smooth-poincare-conjecture#comment250102_97464) to the original question.)  There are many large families of potential counterexamples to the S4PC.  These are smooth 4-manifolds which are homotopy equivalent (and hence homeomorphic) to the 4-sphere, but no one knows how to prove that they are diffeomorphic to the 4-sphere.

(Akbulut and Gompf have made recent progress in showing that some, but not nearly all, of these potential counterexamples are standard 4-spheres, so I think people are more open to the idea that the S4PC might be true than they were four years ago.)

There are similarly many suspected counterexamples to the closely related Andrews–Curtis conjecture.  Andrew Casson has some interesting (and unpublished) numerical evidence that the AC conjecture is false.

So if you are interested in this problem, you might want to spend as much time trying to prove that one of the potential counterexamples is an actual counterexample as you do trying to prove the conjecture.

Comment: Is there a URL to Casson's numerical work? I'd done some myself (http://bit.ly/JzzsKu), but the exponential growth of the AC derivation tree "overpowered" the cluster I was working on. I'd be curious as to Casson's approach.

Comment: I heard about Casson's results from some lectures Casson gave at the 2003 Arkansas Spring Lecture Series.  This page -- http://msp.warwick.ac.uk/gtm/2004/07/ -- refers to this conference.  Perhaps that could be a starting point of a web search.  Yo'av Rieck was the main organizer, so perhaps he could help you track down some notes from Casson's talks.

Comment: If two manifolds are shown by Gompf to be diffeomorphic by Kirby calculus, then they are said to be Gompfomorphic.  

Comment: Oh, dear, "AC" is surely an overloaded abbreviation!

Answer (score 22):

The conjecture in question can also be thought of as the $4$-dimensional PL Poincare conjecture (because low-dimensional PL manifolds, including those of dimension $4$, carry a unique smooth structure) and this is how it is understood in most references mentioned below.

Some interesting approaches to the conjecture and its special cases can be found in several papers by Frank Quinn (some based on TQFTs and others in more classical spirit) and in some papers by Robert Craggs.

Much of the effort has been focused on the group-theoretic [Andrews–Curtis](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-02/S0002-9939-1965-0173241-8) conjecture, whose validity would imply that PL (or smooth) homotopy $4$-spheres given as handlebodies without $3$-handles are PL (or smoothly) standard. The latter assertion would also follow from the ["Generalized Property R"](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603511) conjecture.
Then there's a separate industry of finding handlebody presentations of simply-connected $4$-manifolds without $3$-handles (see Problems 4.18 and 4.73 in [Kirby's list](http://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ekirby/problems.ps.gz), Section 6 of [Funar and Gadgil - On the geometric simple connectivity of open manifolds](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0006003), Gadgil's preprint [One-handles and concordance kernels for smooth 4-manifolds](https://web.archive.org/web/20120130183427/http://math.iisc.ernet.in/%7Egadgil/papers/OnehndlCK.pdf) and Corollary 3.2 of [Quinn - Dual decomposition of 4-manifolds](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2002-354-04/S0002-9947-01-02940-3); note also Rasmussen's withdrawn paper Perfect Morse functions and exotic S^2 x S^2's (arxiv.org/abs/1005.4674)).

As observed by Curtis in an earlier paper "Homotopy manifolds" (in "Topology of 3-manifolds and related topics"), every compact contractible $2$-polyhedron PL embeds in some PL homotopy $4$-sphere; so if you find one that doesn't PL embed in $S^4$, you're done with the 4D PL Poincaré conjecture. This line of attack inspired some literature on PL embeddings of acyclic $2$-polyhedra in $S^4$ starting I guess with Zeeman's dunce hat paper; see [Livingston - Observations on Lickorish knotting of contractible 4-manifolds](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1978374) for additional references.

There are numerous other approaches and related techniques, e.g. "Gluck twists" and "Akbulut corks". [Kirby's problem list](http://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ekirby/problems.ps.gz) is a good source of further references prior to mid-90s; some other basic references on the Andrews–Curtis conjecture are collected [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110526102338/http://www.sci.ccny.cuny.edu/%7Eshpil/gworld/problems/Back.html) under (O1).

Answer (score 11):

Fastforward $11+\frac12$ years, I thought I'd mention that I tried to do what my original post suggested, which is when I started my PhD and then when I completed my thesis it naturally spawned this project (not a shocker since Hutchings became my advisor). Use certain differential 2-forms (called "near-symplectic") to probe the geometry of potentially exotic 4-spheres — it led to a (null)result,

- Chris Gerig, *No homotopy 4-sphere invariants using ECH = SWF*,  Algebr. Geom. Topol. 21(5): 2543-2569 (2021). DOI:[10.2140/agt.2021.21.2543](https://doi.org/10.2140/agt.2021.21.2543), arXiv:[1905.10938](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.10938), [Project Euclid](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/algebraic-and-geometric-topology/volume-21/issue-5/No-homotopy-4sphere-invariants-using-ECHSWF/10.2140/agt.2021.21.2543.short).

I do strongly believe there is some progress along these lines that can be made by being more clever, especially since gauge theory and symplectic geometry have been good at realizing/detecting exotic structures on smooth 4-manifolds.

Concerning the community's consensus on the truth/falsity of the conjecture, here is an anecdote (first-hand as I was the organizer): During one of the Harvard gauge theory seminars Cliff Taubes commented "I read on Wikipedia that the experts think the smooth Poincaré conjecture is true", and then everyone in the audience laughed; indeed most of the experts were in that audience that day.

Comment: I would be very happy if smooth PC4 is actually true (in fact David Gabai bet that it is true). But at the same time I am very sure that there exists exotic diffeomorphisms on 4-sphere.